# Nested UITableView through a single string

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm making an app that uses a companies internal web service to receive it's records via JSON.  One of the records passed through is called "Section".  Sections are in a single string separated by `~`.  I'm looking for a way to gather all matching sections and display them in the tableview in stages.

Data

`Section1~SectionB~SectionD
Section1~Section4~SectionP
Section3~SectionF~SectionG`

In this case, I want the first TableView to show `Section1` and `Section3`.  If the user taps `Section1`, the tableView should update and show `SectionB` and `Section4`.  When they tap past the last section, either `SectionD` or `SectionP` in this case, the tableView will show only the records that matches the full string.

I know this way of doing it sucks and I'm hoping the backend will be rewritten eventually.  I have some form of idea of getting it to work but I can't get my head around it completely.

Comment: Are you planning to use any libraries, or you want to implement this yourself

Comment: I would prefer to do it myself but I'm open to using libraries should they make my life easier

Comment: do string have line break?

Comment: if you can post more detailed webservice response.

Comment: take a look at [SKSTableView](https://github.com/sakkaras/SKSTableView). might suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

First of all create static `.plist` file and then read that file into code.In your case need to create dictionary dynamically.

Here is the static structure of the `.plist`
[image]

And here is the source code for `ViewController.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UITableView *tblForCollapse;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *arrayOriginal;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *arForTable;

-(void)miniMizeThisRows:(NSArray*)ar;

@end
```

here is the source code for `ViewController.m`

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSDictionary *dTmp = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"plist"]];
    self.arrayOriginal = [dTmp valueForKey:@"Objects"];

    self.arForTable = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [self.arForTable addObjectsFromArray:self.arrayOriginal];
    self.title=@"Sugartin.info";
}

// Customize the number of sections in the table view.
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.arForTable count];
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
    }

    cell.textLabel.text=[[self.arForTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"name"];
    [cell setIndentationLevel:[[[self.arForTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"level"] intValue]];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    NSDictionary *d=[self.arForTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if([d valueForKey:@"Objects"]) {
        NSArray *ar=[d valueForKey:@"Objects"];

        BOOL isAlreadyInserted=NO;

        for(NSDictionary *dInner in ar ){
            NSInteger index=[self.arForTable indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:dInner];
            isAlreadyInserted=(index>0 && index!=NSIntegerMax);
            if(isAlreadyInserted) break;
        }

        if(isAlreadyInserted) {
            [self miniMizeThisRows:ar];
        } else {
            NSUInteger count=indexPath.row+1;
            NSMutableArray *arCells=[NSMutableArray array];
            for(NSDictionary *dInner in ar ) {
                [arCells addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:count inSection:0]];
                [self.arForTable insertObject:dInner atIndex:count++];
            }
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:arCells withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
        }
    }
}

-(void)miniMizeThisRows:(NSArray*)ar{

    for(NSDictionary *dInner in ar ) {
        NSUInteger indexToRemove=[self.arForTable indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:dInner];
        NSArray *arInner=[dInner valueForKey:@"Objects"];
        if(arInner && [arInner count]>0){
            [self miniMizeThisRows:arInner];
        }

        if([self.arForTable indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:dInner]!=NSNotFound) {
            [self.arForTable removeObjectIdenticalTo:dInner];
            [self.tblForCollapse deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:
                                                    [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexToRemove inSection:0]
                                                    ]
                                  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
        }
    }
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Following is the Output of your requirement.

[image]

[Also you can download the same tutorial from here.](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nimitparekh/files/Cell%20Min%20max/cellMaxMinDemo%202.zip/download)